# Sorting Listview mixes up the SubItems.Item(i).ForeColor and .Bold settings

Tags: listview, ms-access, sorting, vba

Just created a ListView control with VBA (Access 2007). 
Initializing, filling up and sorting the ListView works fine so far.
But using  the SubItems.Item(i).ForeColor and SubItems.Item(i).Bold properties I am facing some strange bahavior while sorting the list. 
For the first run everything is ok. But as soon as I sort the ListView, the .ForeColor and .Bold settings are mixed up. In fact it looks like the .ForeColor and .Bold settings are stick to the ListView row itself and not to the data.
If that is correct it would mean, I have to reapply the ForeColor and .Bold settings each time the ListView has been sorted=

Is this a normal behavior, or did I miss something?

Thanks for your help
rene

Answer (score 1):

I found when working with colour properties etc with listviews that you are best to avoid doing it on the .item property and are better with the list reference like this:

```
ListView.ListItems(RowNumber).ListSubItems(ColNumber).ForeColor = vbBlue
ListView.ListItems(RowNumber).ListSubItems(ColNumber).Bold = True
```

These seem to sort ok without messing up the order : )

Comment: Problem solved. It was because I used the Windows API to sort the ListView control and not the ListView builtin functions